# How can i get xy-data set Android aFreeChart

Tags: android, charts, jfreechart, achartengine

i use AFreeChart chart(XYPlot) lib for my project. However i want to get xy-dataset values when i touch curve points, do you have any idea is there any onClicklistener for graph points?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with aFreeChart but based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16150178/68969) answer the solution would seem to be to add a [`ChartTouchListener`](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/afreechart/src/org/afree/chart/ChartTouchListener.java?r=42) to your chart, this will allow you to access the `ChartEntity` under the touch point if there is one.